# Android Effective Navigation Example . The Fragment is created multiple times

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-viewpager

I was playing around standard Effective navigation example of Android which shows how to create swipeable views

The code can be downloaded from the following page :
http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

In the getView() method , a new fragment is created. Isn't this a bad practice and wouldn't it cause Memory leaks .

```
public Fragment getItem(int i) {

    switch (i) {

        case 0:
            // The first section of the app is the most interesting -- it offers
            // a launchpad into the other demonstrations in this example application.
            return new LaunchpadSectionFragment();

        default:
            // The other sections of the app are dummy placeholders.
            Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, i + 1);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
    }
}
```

Comment: what do mean by memory leak here?

Comment: A new instance of Fragment is created in getView() each time. I can see in the debugger that DummySectionFragments are getting new ids.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the Viewpager Documentation carefully it provides two adapters to its 
contents:

From Android Developer Docs

**FragmentPagerAdapter:**

> This version of the pager is best for use when there are a handful of typically more static fragments to be paged through, such as a set of tabs. The fragment of each page the user visits will be kept in memory, though its view hierarchy may be destroyed when not visible. This can result in using a significant amount of memory since fragment instances can hold on to an arbitrary amount of state.

**FragmentStatePagerAdapter**

> This version of the pager is more useful when there are a large number of pages, working more like a list view. When pages are not visible to the user, their entire fragment may be destroyed, only keeping the saved state of that fragment. This allows the pager to hold on to much less memory associated with each visited page as compared to FragmentPagerAdapter at the cost of potentially more overhead when switching between pages.

As you can see you can implemt the adadpter depending on your requirement and if there is a large set of data you can implement FragmentStatePagerAdapter which takes care of the lifecycle of the fragments.

If you dont want to create Fragments dynamically you can instantiate a single fragment in your constructor and return it on the getview with different data with

```
myFragment.setArguments(Bundle Instance);
```

Comment: My use case is something like this : I have two fragements which are shown inside two different tabs .The fragment 1 shows a list if images dynamically being fetched from different urls and the user can add images to their favorite and the url is stored in the database. The second tab is the favorite fragment whcih reads the urls from database and shows the images in list. So what i need is if the user goes back to first tab and comes to the favorite tab it should notify the list if data is changed in database. But since a new Fragment is getting created , I loose the reference of list adapter

Comment: You could try Viewpager.setOffscreenPageLimit (int numofrags) which prevents the fragments from being recreated more info here( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int))

Comment: You could try a interface from which you can invalidate the data in the favorites tab  every time the user adds or removes data to the favorite list or simply you can refetch the data in onresume of the fragment since every time the fragment toggle visiblity onpause and onresume called.

Comment: The onResume() is not triggered when using a View Pager . So far that i have created an interface which simulates the Lifecycle methods .